# PDF documentation of SikaliX

Tags: sikuli-x

¿Where is pdf documentation of SikuliX?

I have searched in Google, but I don't find much about it, or the existing documentality is very old. I am interested in this IDE to automate my work. I made a [small article about it](https://espaciotecnologico.co/automatizar-operaciones-en-el-sistema-en-linux/), but it is very basic. Thank you so much.